# In List Of List I am not able to assign List of list to SOSL

Tags: list

```
list<list<sObject>> Mylist = New list<list<sObject>>();
Mylist = [ FIND {IBM} IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Account(name),Lead(name)];
System.debug(Mylist);
```

[image]

Comment: Why bother with the "new List<List<SObject>>()" assignment when you immediately re-assign the value of MyList anyway? I see so many people doing this for absolutely no good reason.

Answer (score 1):

The `{IBM}` is confusing the compiler as curly brackets are very significant in the language.

This will compile:

```
Mylist = [ FIND 'IBM' IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Account(name),Lead(name)];
```

or if you want the search term to vary:

```
String searchTerm = 'IBM';
Mylist = [ FIND :searchTerm IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Account(name),Lead(name)];
```